# Programmer: Flex 4.5 Pre seleting a Radio Button

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm using an XML File and so far things are OK. But now I'm trying to pre-select a Radio button and I can find no where to give an example just ways to detect click event and thing like that. The selected value is a string coming from the XML file. There are five radio buttons How do I match the string to the radio button.

Thanks in advance and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you give us some code to work with?  What have you tried?  It is easier to help if you can give us an example to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioButtons need to be in same group to prevent multiple selection. There is property for that:

```
myRadioButton.group
```

For select, there is property:

```
myRadioButton.selected //true or false
```

And you can compare string from your xml if its equal with:

```
myRadioButton.value
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this is what I needed still trying to get my head around the Flex Environment - A PHP Programmer :)

Comment: Here is the code to pre-select a radio button in Flex 4.5 
First Create an empty array
`var arr:Array = [];`
New Create a temp var to hold the radio results from loop 
`var rb:RadioButton;`
New setup the radio for the loop
`var idx:int;<br>
 var len:int = LabTypeInput.numRadioButtons;`
Then Loop through the button and test for a match

`LabType = event.result.Checklist.Checklist06.LabType; // Source
for (idx=0; idx<len; idx++) {<br>
   rb = LabTypeInput.getRadioButtonAt(idx);<br>
   if(rb.label==LabType) {<br>
      LabTypeInput.getRadioButtonAt(idx).selected = true;<br>
   }<br>
}`

Comment: For some reason i actually thought you have experience with programming, and the problem was more with flex / as3 things. So i think my subconscious was right :) Anyway i guess that is why i didnt put any example how actually loop through the values. If you need help with that, just ask.